# Why do inorganic lasers not experience problems due to triplet loss?

Tags: atomic-physics, material-science, laser, crystals, light-emitting-diodes

A major problem for building organic lasers (especially if aiming for electrical pumping) is the creation of triplets that cannot classically photoluminesce (forbidden transition) and can interact with other existing triplets or cause absorption losses. Why is this not a problem in inorganic materials? Is it because inorganic lasers are made of heavier elements that allow intersystem crossing (heavy atom effect) and exploit phosphorescence? What transitions are used for lasing in inorganic lasers?

thank you

Comment: There is a great deal of information dealing with the theory and practical aspects of inorganic laser media. A very simple Nd:YAG discussion is [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/158765/79678) and see the first two referenced books for much deeper information.

Answer (score 1):

First, inorganic lasers are specially designed to optimize stimulated emission, as this excellent book mentions (Laser fundamentals by W. T. Silfvast [ISBN:9780511616426]):

> Laser gain media produced in solid-state dielectric laser materials are in some ways analogous to organic dyes in solution. The laser species consit of ionic species, such as chromium ions (Cr3+) grown or doped within a host material such as aluminium oxide (Al203), [...].
> This is analogous to the organic dye laser in which the dye molecules are suspended in a solvent. In the case of the solid-state host material, the host behaves as a matrix that suspends the laser ions, rendering them isolated and effectively 'frozen' at nearly regularly spaced locations, so the ions are approximately equidistant from each other. This isolation of the ions prevents undesired interactions between them, which would produce collisional decay (quenching) of the laser levels instead of the desired radiative decay.

The author mentions the fact that inorganic lasers also suffer from excited-state absorption:

> Many of the transition metal solid-state lasers also suffer from excited-state absorption (ESA) [...]. The ESA cross section in alexandrite is less than 10% of the stimulated emission cross section at the center of the gain spectrum at 750 nm.

Then, as explained in this excellent book (Organic Solid-State Lasers by S. Forget & S. Chenais [ISBN: 978-3-642-36705-2]):

> The main difference between excitons in inorganic and organic semiconductors arises from the fact that in organic semiconductors electrons are only weakly delocalized over a small length scale even in the case of molecular crystals or conjugated polymers. As a result they have two important peculiarities as compared to their inorganic counterparts.
>
> 1. The first one is a considerable binding energy, linked to the strong localization of excitons in a single molecular site.
> 2. The second difference is the existence of well-defined spin states (singlet and triplet) for excitons which makes them no different from isolated molecules in this respect.

The introduction of this paper [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3072.pdf] should clarify a part of your question:

> Unlike common inorganic semiconductors, where thermal energy is sufficient to mix between spin states efficiently, the energetics of the triplet states of organic materials play a determining role and must be considered with care. Organic light-emitting diodes are a prime example of the importance of the triplet state, because exciton formation through electrical injection is dictated by the spin statistics found in organic disordered films [...].

Comment: am I understanding correctly that the larger delocalization of exciton in inorganic semiconductors is responsible for the mixing of spin states? why would this be the case?